# An issue about IPv6 address in Scapy

Tags: python, ipv6, scapy

I'm using scapy in python2.6 and met an issue about the IPv6 address:

```
from scapy.all import *
p = IPv6(src = '1:0:0:1::1', dst = '2:0:0:2::2')
print p.src, p.dst
p.show()
```

it seems that scapy replaced every continuation of '0' with '::', the result of the print turned out to be:

```
1::1::1 2::2::2
```

and the p.show() part raised an exception complaining illegal syntax for IP address.

Is this a problem unsolved in scapy or are there some configuration not right in scapy? thx in advance.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with scapy - please report it to them on their website. sure there is an issue tracker. Or you can correct their code and send a change-set. IPv6 addresses should only contain `::` once.

Comment: 4 years later, is seem to bump into the same issue on fedora 26... still no fix on this? I use the scapy shipped in the fedora 26 repo. Will see if there is a newer version that hopefully doesn't have this issue

Comment: This changset fixes my problem:
[Link](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/363/files/47fca06543688a15ea4f8fd1dbea524a86e27ed1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issue on my Fedora 26 installation. After some searching in the github issue-list of the scapy project. I've discovered following bug-reports and fixes:

[Bugreport: Zero block in IPv6 route prefix misinterpreted #359](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/359)

[changeset 1](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/363/files/47fca06543688a15ea4f8fd1dbea524a86e27ed1)
(note: for linux/unix only )

[changeset 2](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/commit/fcb62e79a1e798a2f314fbf815f726c1365a1516)
(note: for windows and linux/unix )

These changes were made in Dec 16/Jan 17. Version 2.3.3 dates from oct 2016. So when 2.3.4 is released, they will contain these 2 fixes.